# Functions to do MLE and MSE calculations in R

Tags: linear-regression

Are there libraries available or does one have to write these functions from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Metrics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Metrics/Metrics.pdf) package for R?